# jQuery custom selection

Tags: jquery

I'd like to extend jQuery selection so that it treats a given selection value as an ID.

For example, when you do `$("foo.bar")` , jQuery will try to select all elements with the tag name foo and the class bar, but I want jQuery to select the element with an ID of `foo.bar`. Instead of having to escape dots and prepend a `#` each time, I'd like to add to jQuery as a function so that I can do something like `$("id:foo.bar")`.

Is this possible with jQuery? If so, can anyone show me some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiousity...why?  readability?

Comment: My projects uses Spring MVC where nested element names such as foo.bar are very common. I need to select these elements a lot and it would be cumbersome having to prepend ID's with a number sign and more importantly, escape dots every time.

Comment: Are you aware of the performance hit you'll suffer by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace ID selection with an attribute filter, it will have to test every element on the page for that ID instead of using `document.getElementById`.

If you want a little more convenience, just create your own wrapper. you can use jQuery's namespace if you want:

```
jQuery.byId = function(id){return $(document.getElementById(id));};

$.byId('foo.bar').addClass('something');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome. I would've accepted this as the answer but it's too late...

Comment: @Tom: You can change the accepted answer, but that doesn't matter to me. I just wanted to be sure that you and future readers know that doing a universal selection followed by a custom attribute filter is really bad if you care at all about performance.

Answer (score 3):

It is. You can create you own selectors by extending `.expr[]`. Example:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
   'id': function(elem, i, attr){   
      return( elem.id === attr[3] );
   }
});
```

Usage would be:

```
$(':id(foo.bar)');
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/cwwGk/1/

Answer (score 2):

you can do `$("[id=foo.bar]")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have specific code to do this. Be aware that overriding the global behavior of jquery may break plugins that others have made. If you can you should use the 'sub' feature of jquery 1.5. It is designed specifically to 'sub'stitute jquery features while retaining the default functionality for other plugins.

Comment: this functionality is now removed (was deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9)